# Multi-tenant Azure AD Authentication Permission Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am new to Azure AD authentication. I have created a app in azure and made it multi-tenant and set its permissions as follow

- Sign in and read user profile
- Read directory data

Here is my `Startup.Auth.cs` code

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        private string graphResourceID = "https://graph.windows.net";
        private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        private string authority = aadInstance + "common";
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        // instead of using the default validation (validating against a single issuer value, as we do in line of business apps), 
                        // we inject our own multitenant validation logic
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        SecurityTokenValidated = (context) => 
                        {
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;

                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                            string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                            string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                                code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceID);

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                        {
                            context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                            context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });

        }
    }
```

But when I try to run application and login then it gives me error

```
    You can't access this application 
    XXXXXXX needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. 
    Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

    Have an admin account? Sign in with that account 
    Return to the application without granting consent
```

Answer (score 1):

An Admin has to Grant permissions first so that other users would be able to access the resources. Try following steps

1. Login to portal as Admin
2. Go to your App registration blade
3. Click `Required Permissions`
4. In the permissions blade on top click `Grant Permissions` link.
5. Read the confirmation message and click OK.

Now try to login with Non-Admin User.

Hope [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview) helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did same as you suggested, but still getting same error. I am trying to login admin account because right now admin is only user in directory.

Comment: are you able to login to portal with the same account and be able to set permissions for this app with same clientId ?

Comment: Yes and everything works fine. i am using different browser for this. In one browser Im logged in as admin in my azure portal and using other browser I am trying to run app

Comment: Ok. I think you are trying to access `Graph Resouce`. Did you give access to `Microsoft Graph` resource API to your app?  If not, in the `Required Persmissions` add `Microsoft Graph` API.

Comment: Actually `Visual Studio 2015` has created all this code it self. When we try to created a new project in VS 2015 It gives option for authentication and then it creates whole code and app in azure itself. Here we are using azure graph only.

Comment: I also tried after adding `Microsoft Graph` but still same error

Comment: Ok. Hope https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview helps...

Comment: @user3881465 Does the admin account you login has `Global administrator` directory role ?

Comment: @Nan Yu - MSFT sorry I am new to azure. please guide me how to check `Global administrator` ? by the way I am owner of this azure subscription and I have created this `Active Directory` myself.

Comment: I think your admin account is the `Global administrator` role . And please confirm the application you grant permission (by clicking `Grant Permissions` button ) is the same application with the one you config in web app ?

Comment: @Nan Yu - MSFT yes sure. Please let me know if you need any info. I will be online after 11 hours. thanks for your support.

Comment: Then try to add prompt=admin_consent to the URL to do admin consent with admin account , please see [this document](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/01/24/Admin-Consent-for-Permissions-in-Azure-Active-Directory.aspx)